# google-play-scraper doesn't scrape all reviews

Tags: python, web-scraping

I tried to scrape the review for an app using the google-play-scraper package. I followed the code from their readme on github: https://github.com/JoMingyu/google-play-scraper. But it doesn't seem to scrape all reviews!

I'm not sure whether it's possible to scrape all reviews as the lang and country arguments default to 'en' and 'us'. But I was trying to scrape several apps that are exclusively used in Germany using 'de' for country and language. I know there will be some people with a foreign play store account who reviewed the app but for an app that only exists in Germany, this share shouldn't be too high. But for many apps I've tried, the difference between the number of reviews stated on google play's website and the number of reviews that are scraped is just implausible.

Here's my code:

```
from google_play_scraper import app
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from google_play_scraper import Sort, reviews_all
app_reviews = reviews_all(
    'de.flaschenpost.app',
    sleep_milliseconds=0,
    lang='de',
    country='de',
    sort=Sort.NEWEST
)
```

For this app, Google Play has 69,600 reviews, but only 7,608 are scraped.
Other examples: de.hafas.android.db (184,247 reviews, 51,552 scraped), de.materna.bbk.mobile.app (24,401 reviews, 12,896 scraped).

Am I missing something? Thanks a lot!

EDIT: Thanks to Joaquin for pointing me in the right direction. All scraped reviews include some comments, i.e. the larger number probably includes all ratings, also those who only left 1-5 stars and didn't write anything!

Comment: Probably of those 69k "reviews" only 7608 are reviews and the others are just ratings.

Comment: You're probably right! All reviews have non-null values for the column content. I didn't know there is a difference between reviews and ratings. I thought reviews_all would scrape all reviews/ratings, no matter whether the user left a comment or not. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: This question should be asked in github issues of the repoi

Comment: I will, and close it here, thanks! I will leave a note here if I get help on github.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Joaquin for pointing me in the right direction. All scraped reviews include some comments, i.e. the larger number probably includes all ratings, also those who only left 1-5 stars and didn't write anything!

Comment: Seems more like a comment than a response