# Google Play Scraper reviews_all is inconsistent

Tags: python, github, web-scraping, google-play

On this code, I run it multiple times, and it shows different results each time. Sometimes 199, 398, 597, 1194. Any solutions to this problems?

```
from google_play_scraper import Sort, reviews_all
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

package_name = 'com.facebook.katana'

app_reviews = reviews_all(
    package_name,
    sleep_milliseconds=0,  # defaults to 0
    lang='id',  # specify the language, e.g., 'en' for English
    country='id',  # specify the country, e.g., 'us' for the United States
    sort=Sort.NEWEST,  # specify the sorting order
    count=10000,
)

num_reviews = len(app_reviews)
print("Number of reviews imported:", num_reviews)
```

I already check similar question from these:
https://github.com/JoMingyu/google-play-scraper
[google-play-scraper doesn't scrape all reviews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75473985/google-play-scraper-doesnt-scrape-all-reviews)

But none seems to have the same problems as I am.